# Language C: Why does my assignment statement ruin my data?

Tags: c

Take a look at this code:

```
void insert(Poly **A, int degree, int coef2) {
    heapSize = heapSize+1;
    Poly *key;

    if (heapSize == 1) {        // heap was originally empty
        key->coef = coef2;
        key->degree = degree;
        A[heapSize-1] = key;
        return;
    }

    // create an "minus infinity" degree poly 
    int keyDegree = degree;

    key->coef = coef2;
    key->degree = MIN_INT;

    A[heapSize-1] = key ;
    heapIncreaseKey(A, heapSize-1, keyDegree);
}
```

Poly is a struct whose members are both of type int. "A" is an array of Poly pointers.
Whenever the statement "A[heapSize-1] = key" (in the if block) is executed, the members of "key" change for some reason to "junk" values. For example, just before that statement is executed, the values of the members of "key" are 5 and 6. After this statement is executed, the values change to some 8 digit junk numbers. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are missing

```
key = malloc(sizeof(Poly));
```

Declaring `key` gives you a pointer, but it doesn't point at a valid location.  Dereferencing `key` causes undefined behaviour.

**EDIT**

Also, it looks like `heapsize` is a global constant while `A` is a pointer to the heap.  Having a global variable recording the size of a non-global seems strange.

I would make `heapsize` a variable with the same scope as `A`, and pass a pointer to it as an argument to functions dealing with `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I understand what you mean. The thing is, i have to write my algorithms to be "cache-efficient". Does the fact that I will be allocating the structures on the heap affect whether or not my system will use cache more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

`key` is an uninitialized pointer, and then you dereference it and assign values into the nonexistent place it points to.  This would have been caught by valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate memory for key and change a signature to pass in size for the A array. Verify that the heapsize is still within allocated range for A.
Even better, you don't need key variable if you refactor to keep structures rather than pointers in your array of Poly's. Then you could just assign your two inputs into the A directly with something like
     A[heapSize].coef=coef2;
Also you could simplify things a bit by using heapSize in your function without incrementing it in the first line and only increment it at the point of exit. This way you don't need to use heapSize-1 everywhere.

Comment: I noticed you worry about efficiency here. Grapevine structure with an array of pointers allocated on the heap is almost never efficient. See if you can leave with an array of structures that you allocate upfront and not an array of pointers.

Comment: Yeah I have to make sure my code uses cache efficiently because I will be dealing with large data. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

key is an uninitialized pointer, and you are writing to it.

That way lies strongly undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

key doesn't point to anything. Also, the allocated length of 'A' is not provided.
Recommend you bone up on 'malloc', etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to malloc your pointer before use it :) !